# Symfony2 : Adding / updating entity in PUT route

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, put

I have a PUT route that updates a user entity with the request data. This works but I am having to call setters on this entity, but I am thinking there might be a better way, where the request data can be applied directly without calling setters for each field. I am using Doctrine. Here is my sample code:

```
    $data = $this->getRequest()->request->all();            
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $entity = new Entity();
    $entity = $em->getRepository('SomeBundle:Entity')->find($id);
    $entity->setParamA($data['A']);
    // ... etc

    if (!empty($entity))
    {
        $em->persist($entity) // flush, etc. I have also tried merge but it removes existing fields
    }
```

How can I simply update $entity with the $data from request without calling setters? If I have a hundred fields, it doesn't make sense to manually call setters, what if there were even more fields?

Comment: There is ,[Symfony Form](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html)